# Build to directory where changes were detected

Tags: webpack

## The Problem

I'm trying to create a **Webpack** config file that will be able to watch all subdirectories and create a build-folder with that includes a build-file with the changes from **only** that directory.

## What I want to happen

**Project Architecture**

```
myWebpackTest
---- Proj1
   ---- src
      ---- index.js

---- Proj2
   ---- src
      ---- index.js

---- webpack.config.js
```

I want to be able to run something like `npm run webpack` from the root directory and when it finds a change in any of the subdirectories, **Proj1**, **Proj2**, it will then create a **build** folder in the root of that specific directory and include only the changes inside the **index.js** file.

**Example output**

```
myWebpackTest
---- Proj1
   ---- dist
      ---- build.js  // new build from the changes in Proj1/src/index.js
   ---- src
      ---- index.js  // only made a change to Proj1/src/index.js

---- Proj2
   ---- src
      ---- index.js

---- webpack.config.js
```

As a side note, I don't mind workarounds as a solution if this isn't something webpack can do on its own. I just need something that's solid and automated.

I've looked over [Issue #1189 on the Webpack Repo](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1189) and it seems that they are on to something here but not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be answering my own question.

**Webpack**'s **entry** property in the **config** file accepts multiple data types from **string**, **array**, **object**, and **function**. What we need to do is find a way to dynamically create an **entry** object depending. After that, the **key**, or property name, will be used in the **output** property in the config file.

## Example project architecture

```
myWebpackTest
---- Projects
   ---- Proj1
      ---- src
         ---- index.js

   ---- Proj2
      ---- src
         ---- index.js

---- webpack.config.js
```

When we create our **entry** object we want to make sure that the **output** will receive the correct path and create a build script in the correct directory.

## webpack.config.js

```
const glob = require('glob')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: glob.sync('./Projects/**/index.js').reduce((acc, path) => {
        const entry = path.replace('/index.js', '')
        acc[entry] = path
        return acc
    }, {}),

    output: {
        filename: './[name]/main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname)
    },

    mode: 'production'
}
```

What happens here is we're using the **Glob** API to find each of our **index.js** files inside of **ANY** sub-directory, using the **wild card** or double-asterisk, inside of the **Projects** root directory and using **reduce()** on the returned value, an array of strings, to dynamically create our **entry** object. This particular example would return

```
{
  './Projects/Proj1/src': './Projects/Proj1/src/index.js',
  './Projects/Proj2/src': './Projects/Proj2/src/index.js',
}
```

In our **output** we use two properties, **filename** and **path**, to specify where we want to output our builds.

**filename**: Basically, **[name]** will take the **key** from our **entry** object and replace itself with that **key** or it will default to **main**.

**path**: We need to provide an absolute path or **Webpack** will throw an error. I'm sure you could just place this in the **filename** property but I felt that this looks cleaner.

Just for clarity, after you run `npm run webpack` or however you decide to bundle your files your structure will then look like

```
myWebpackTest
---- Projects
   ---- Proj1
      ---- src
         ---- index.js
         ---- main.js  // new build based on Proj1

   ---- Proj2
      ---- src
         ---- index.js
         ---- main.js  // new build based on Proj2

---- webpack.config.js
```

I'd just like to give credit to [Sanjay Purswani and his article](https://hackernoon.com/webpack-creating-dynamically-named-outputs-for-wildcarded-entry-files-9241f596b065). While it wasn't 100% correct in my case it did point me in the right direction.